# how to catch the full url including #

Tags: php, url

How can i catch the current full url including the **#** sign when it is in it?

My url looks like this: http://example.com/spf#users/admin

When using this code:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
echo $url;
```

he outputs this only: http://example.com/spf
It should also catch the **#users/admin** behind it

Comment: PHP doesn't receive the fragment information because it's client-only. You can catch it with javascript though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plz Refer Below Link

[Get Full Url in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

at Client Side You can use javascript to get hash value with window.location.hash

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible with "standard" HTTP to get the URL fragment as this value is never sent to the server. You would need following JavaScript on the client side.

Use `window.location.hash` in JavaScript and do any operation.